# Elixir Phoenix template get image url from array

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an array of objects like so

```rb
[%{id:1, url:'image.jpg'}, %{id:2, url:'image2.jpg'}]
```

My phoenix template looks like so

```rb
<%= for item <- array() do %>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="<%= static_path(@conn, item.url ) %>" alt="">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Given that I'm already interpolating and pointing to my static path how do I interpolate twice or rather point to the image url after `@conn`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your array of objects is not a valid Elixir term. Please correct.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. What output are you getting and what's the expected output?

Comment: Hmm, the code doesn't look ok. What's `[{id:1, url:'image.jpg'}, {id:2, url:'image2.jpg'}]`? maybe `[%{id: 1, url: 'image.jpg'}, %{id: 2, url: 'image2.jpg'}]`... And what is `item.url???`?

Comment: @Grych yup corrected the code there. item.url is me extracting the property url out of it. The question marks were just to resemble that that's the piece I'm trying to access which I currently can't via item.url since phoenix expects a string. The error I get as is `static_path/2 expects a path starting with / as argument`

Comment: @Dogbert I'm expecting to get the string that is with the object, in this case image.jpg or image2.jpg. Instead I get the error `static_path/2 expects a path starting with / as argument`

Comment: Please include error messages in the question itself from next time. I bet you'd have got an answer from someone within minutes of posting the question if you had included that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to prepend a `/` to `url` to make it work with `static_path`. I'm assuming you have a double quoted String in the list as if you had single quote you'd be getting a different error. To prepend a `/`, change:

```
static_path(@conn, item.url)
```

to

```
static_path(@conn, "/" <> item.url)
```

Comment: Won't work as there is charlist in `item.url` instead of String. Should be something like `to_string(['/' | item.url])`

Comment: Like I said, I assumed it's a typo because if it really was a charlist, OP would be getting this error instead: `no function clause matching in Phoenix.Endpoint.Adapter.static_path/2`. You can try it by running `static_path(_, 'foo')`.

Comment: Sorry, I must be blind, I missed this.